# How to skip to a line via character seeking in Python

Tags: python, loops, text

If I have a text file that has a bunch of random text before I get to the stuff I actually want, how do I move the file pointer there?

Say for example my text file looks like this:

```
#foeijfoijeoijoijfoiej ijfoiejoi jfeoijfoifj  i jfoei joi jo ijf eoij oie jojf
#feoijfoiejf   ioj oij       oi jo ij   i joi jo ij oij  ####  oijroijf 3## # o
#foeijfoiej i jo i  iojf 3 ##  #io joi joij oi j## io joi joi j3# 3i ojoi joij
# The stuff I care about
```

(The hashtags are a part of the actual text file)

How do I move the file pointer to the line of stuff I care about, and then how would I get python to tell me the number of the line, and start the reading of the file there?

I've tried doing a loop to find the line that the last hashtag is in, and then reading from there, but I still need to get rid of the hashtag, and need the line number.

Comment: You need to find something consistent to work from so `#f` for example occurs at the start of each line, so skip all lines that start with that with an if statement. Can you spot any other patterns that you could work with?

Comment: The problem is #f won't necessarily be at the start of each line, there will always be a hashtag at the front of the line, though. 

I wanted to use .rfind('#') like you would on a singular string, but I don't know how to apply the .rfind() to the entire text document without making the whole document a string.

Comment: I'd just loop through each line and check the first `char` of each, if it is a `#` or something else predictable skip until you hit the content and start reading from there onward.

Comment: It'd be easier if you post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [readlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) function. This will return a list containing each line. You can use a `for` loop to parse through each line, searching for what you need, then obtain the number of the line via its index in the list. For instance:

```
with open('some_file_path.txt') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
object = '#the line I am looking for'
for line in contents:
    if object in line:
        line_num = contents.index(object)
```

To get rid of the pound sign, just use the [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) function. Eg. `new_line = line.replace('#','')`

Comment: That reads every line in the file into memory at once, even when you don't want all of them, and slurps the rest of the file too, even if you want to process only part of it. If the OP is concerned with seeking to just past the junk, they're probably trying to avoid unnecessary I/O/memory use, which this does nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

You can't seek to it directly without knowing the size of the junk data or scanning through the junk data. But it's not too hard to wrap the file in [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to discard lines until you see the "good" data, after which it iterates through all remaining lines:

```
import itertools

# Or def a regular function that returns True until you see the line
# delimiting the beginning of the "good" data
not_good = '# The stuff I care about\n'.__ne__

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in itertools.dropwhile(not_good, f):
        ... You'll iterate the lines at and after the good line ...
```

If you actually need the file descriptor positioned appropriately, not just the lines, this variant should work:

```
import io

with open(filename) as f:
    # Get first good line
    good_start = next(itertools.dropwhile(not_good, f))

    # Seek back to undo the read of the first good line:
    f.seek(-len(good_start), io.SEEK_CUR)

    # f is now positioned at the beginning of the line that begins the good data
```

You can tweak this to get the actual line number if you really need it (rather than just needing the offset). It's a little less readable though, so explicit iteration via `enumerate` may make more sense if you need to do it (left as exercise). The way to make Python work for you is:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Py2 only
from operator import itemgetter

with open(filename) as f:
    linectr = itertools.count()
    # Get first good line
    # Pair each line with a 0-up number to advance the count generator, but
    # strip it immediately so not_good only processes lines, not line nums 
    good_start = next(itertools.dropwhile(not_good, map(itemgetter(0), zip(f, linectr))))

    good_lineno = next(linectr) # Keeps the 1-up line number by advancing once

    # Seek back to undo the read of the first good line:
    f.seek(-len(good_start), io.SEEK_CUR)

    # f is now positioned at the beginning of the line that begins the good data
```